Reading CSV with newlines into SQL DB using ADF
I have a datadump of CSV files which I download into a blob daily.
The file contains columns such as ID, dates and also fields for comments.
Within the comments fields, Newlines are often used. This results in ADF reading them as new lines, despite them being within quoted fields.
I have the row delimiter set to ";", so I don't know why he reads them as newlines. The dataset settings are attached. enter image description here
When I use the ADF CSV preview in the BLOB, the lines are not split, also see the attached file.enter image description here
However when I look at the data preview, ADF does read them as separate lines.enter image description here
I have been trying to switch around the delimiter and quote settings, but I was not able to keep the comment field in 1 row. What can I do?
I tried multiple dataset source settings including Double Quote, Single Quote.
CSV:
id|brondocdate_afv|brondocdate_opv|brondocnr_afv|brondocnr_opv|mutator_id|creator_id|createdate|mut_dat|conditional|owners_id|bevoegd_gezag_id|uitvoerende_id|zaak_hoofddeel|zaak_identificatie|kenmerk|zaaktypecode_id|zaakproduct_id|doorlooptijd|doorlooptijd_eenheid|zaak_status_id|zaak_status_code|zaak_reeks_id|wachten|kanaal|kenmerk_bron|omschrijving_kort|url|hyperlink_omschrijving|trefwoord|authentiek|toelichting|klantinformeren|conformservicenorm|startdatum|einddatum|einddatum_gepland|einddatum_uiterlijk|doelgroep_id|datum_start_planning|manual_plan_id|auto_plan_id|gepland|einddatum_verwacht|resultaatcode_id|resultaatomschrijving|resultaat_toelichting|pub_pip|pub_internet|zaak_adres|initiator|thesaurus_id|archiefcode_id|vernietingsgrond_id|bewaartermijn|bewaartermijn_id|datumarchief|datum_vernietigen|archiveren|voordragenvernietigen|startflow|locatiedossier|xcoordinaat|ycoordinaat|open_module|brs_koppel_id|afnemer|aangemaakt|lastsendcode|grondslag_id|activiteit_id|showproclinkwindow|kernmerk_initiator|kernmerk_lgr|resultaat_id|zaaksubproduct_id|doorlooptijd_streef|prod_doorlooptijd_wet|prod_doorlooptijd_streef|prod_doorlooptijd_eenheid|referentie_code|kengetal|kanaal_id|vervolg_kanaal|datum_vernietigd|prive|meerwerk|admin_prio|openbaarheid_id|overleg_nodig|bestuurlijk_gevoelig|zaak_bool1|zaak_bool2|zaak_bool3|leges|leges_nieuw|ingangsdatum|betalings_periode|datum_van|datum_tot|datum_opbouw_van|datum_opbouw_tot|prioriteit|klant_label_id|z_perceel|z_nr1|z_nr2|z_postcode|z_woonplaatscode_id|z_burgerservicenummer|z_voorletters|z_voorvoegsels|z_geslachtnaam|z_geboortedatum|z_kvknummer|z_handelsregisternummer|z_statutairenaam|z_handelsnaam|z_nr3|blokkeren|dossier_wijziger_id|koppel_wijzig_dat|geexporteerd|dso_verzoeknummer|zaak_codetabel_id|zaak_memo|z_samengesteld_adres|prioritering|uuid|taken_aangemaakt|resultaat_uuid|zaak_datum_1|zaak_datum_2|teller|dso_projectid|kengetal_resterend_uren|betalingsindicatie|betalingsindicatie_toelichting|laatstebetaaldatum|geparticipeerd|participatiewijze|participatieresultaat
"42925|||||""981""|""954""|""2023-02-15 14:29:35+01""|""2024-04-19 16:42:37+02""|""N""|""1""|""1000000166""|""228""|""H""|""Z2023-003006""||""12""|""1304""|""21""|""Dag""|""76""||""200""||||""nvt   Barnsteen 1, generiek""||||""N""|""Er is ook een  voor milieu.  Z2023-002921"
"reg. nr. 9390""|||""2023-02-15 14:26:54+01""|""2023-02-28 00:00:00+01""|""2023-03-08 14:26:54+01""|""2023-02-28 00:00:00+01""|||||||||""28-02-2023 11:53 nvt Z2023-003006:"
28-02-2023 11:50 nvt Z2023-003006:
"Wordt afgehandeld onder zaaknummer Z2023-002921""|||||||||""1""|""2023-02-28 00:00:00+01""|""2024-02-28 00:00:00+01""|||||||||""F""|""F""||||""T""|||""278""||""21""|||||||||""F""|""F""|||""F""|""F""||||""0.00""|""0.00""||||||||||||||||||||||||||""2023-11-30 11:50:21.415483+01""||||||||||||""0""||||||||"
Expected result:
3 records.

Provide your sample input data and expected output for that?

@RakeshGovindula I just added it!

If your data have "" around those values, then dataset can read those with below configurations.
This is my source data which have new lines in the rows.

Give the below configurations in the source dataset.

Upon executing the copy activity, it will give the results like below in SQL table.


When I run my CSV's using your settings the ID field gets additional quotes and is not read properly. E.g. the Data preview show the ID field as "42925|||||||".
Also the comments are still spread across 5 different lines instead of 1...
Maybe this has something to do with the CSV file?

Yes, your csv file columns will be divided based on | column delimiter. The | should match the number of the columns in each row. If the number of | are not same in each row and if it is the column delimiter for your csv file, then it will give the null values for the extra columns. Make sure your column count and delimiter count | matches as per the csv file.

For anyone reading this in the future.
It appears that the ADF read my CSV into newlines due to Double Quotes in the comment fields. This could be resolved by also adding the Double Quotes as the Escape Character in the Dataset settings.
